# How to send Get and Post request with POCO Library and OAuth2

Tags: poco-libraries

I have a native window app program,and want access API of gitlab service,hope to get token using name and password with using POCO Library and OAuth2,but I don't know how to send Get and Post request to gitlab with OAuth2,and using POCO Library, please give me a example.

Here is the data that needs to be sent and received.

Requesting access token 
POST request to /oauth/token with parameters:

```
{
  "grant_type"    : "password",
  "username"      : "user@example.com",
  "password"      : "secret"
}
```

Then, you'll receive the access token back in the response:

```
{
  "access_token": "1f0af717251950dbd4d73154fdf0a474a5c5119adad999683f5b450c460726aa",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 7200
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First you need to create a HTTPRequest object like so:

```
Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession* session = Poco::Net::HTTPSessionFactory::defaultFactory().createClientSession(serverUri);
Poco::Net::HTTPRequest request(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, serverUri.getPathAndQuery(), Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
```

Then create a HTMLForm:

```
Poco::Net::HTMLForm form; 
form.add("grant_type", "password");
form.add("client_id", "client token");
form.add("client_secret", "client secret");
form.add("username", "user@example.com");
form.add("password", "secret");
form.prepareSubmit(request);
```

Send the request and write the form data into the output stream of the request:

```
std::ostream& requestStream = session->sendRequest(request);
form.write(requestStream);
```

Get the response out of the session:

```
Poco::Net::HTTPResponse response;
std::istream& responseStream = session->receiveResponse(response);
std::stringstream rawJson;
Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(responseStream, rawJson);
```

Parse the raw JSON:

```
 Poco::JSON::Parser parser;
 Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr authObj =  parser.parse(rawJson).extract<Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr>();
```

Create a new session for next request and attach an authorization header to the request:

```
Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession* dataSession = Poco::Net::HTTPSessionFactory::defaultFactory().createClientSession(dataUri);
Poco::Net::HTTPRequest dataRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, dataUri.getPathAndQuery(), Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
dataRequest.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authObj->get("access_token"));
dataSession->sendRequest(dataRequest);
```

Get the response and read the data from stream:

```
std::stringstream data;
Poco::Net::HTTPResponse dataResponse;
Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(dataSession->receiveResponse(dataResponse), data);
```

Hope it helps or points into the right direction.

Comment: Plain-text HTTP for auth?